# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: e06d7363

Tags: c++, .net, dll, com, com-interop

I developed a Windows form application using C#.NET to test some device. A also have user-mode driver (DLL) developed on Visual C++ (with sources). My C#.NET application is running on my Windows XP platform. When I try to use some class from DLL in the application I get error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {5B145E4D-5D9E-45F6-B580-ADBD48380118} failed due to the following
>   error: e06d7363 Exception from HRESULT: 0xE06D7363.

Please take note that error code is **e06d7363** not **80040154** because there are many solved issues with **80040154** but I couldn't find any solition for **e06d7363**. Just in case my platform is x86, DLL is built for x86 and application is also built for x86.

Another important detail that may be helpful but I can't find the explanation is that I don't get the error on Win7 x86, but I get it on WinXP.

And the last one thing. I have Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 application that works fine with this DLL on my WinXP but I can't implement it on C#.NET.

Comment: It is illegal for a COM component to throw an exception, any error must always be reported back with an HRESULT error code.  You can diagnose the underlying cause for the exception code, the last 3 hex pairs spell "msc" in ASCII.  Which makes it a C++ exception generated by the MSVC++ compiler.  A `throw` without a `catch`.  If you can't debug the C++ code yourself then write a bug report for the author of this code.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you. Yes, I have an opportunity to debug C++ code but I don't know how to do it correctly. For example, I have class definition in my DLL: public: ClassName() { // breakpoint is here }. And I try to create  this object in my application: ClassName O = new ClassName();. I get the COMException but execution don't reach my breakpoint. To compare in case when I use Visual Basic application (I have mentioned it in my topic post) execution DO reach my breakpoint...

Comment: You can trivially make the debugger stop when the exception is thrown.  Ensure unmanaged debugging is enabled, use Debug > Exceptions (VS2015: Debug > Windows > Exception Settings) and tick the thrown checkbox for C++ exceptions.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you! It's solved. I ticked the thrown checkbox for C++ exceptions and got CMemoryException and it was very helpful because I use big CMemFile in DLL. I have just reduced it size.